# Codeigniter user guide - why do they assign CI object by reference and say that it's important

Tags: php, codeigniter

From CodeIgniter User Guide (https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/ancillary_classes.html):

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```

"This is very important. Assigning by reference allows you to use the original CodeIgniter object rather than creating a copy of it".

But normal assignment ($CI = get_instance(); ) would not cause creating a copy of the original CodeIgniter object either, would it?

Answer (score 0):

I think `$CI=get_instance()` does not do copy original.It returns the original. If you look at the system\core\Controller.php  the get_instace() function returns the reference of the controller.I also tested it.Here is my test method how I tested It.

```
public static function function1() {
    $CI = get_instance();
    $CI->config->set_item('item_name', 'item_value');
    echo "inside function 1:".$CI->config->item("item_name")."<br>";


}
public static function function2()
{
    $CI = get_instance();
    echo "inside function 2:".$CI->config->item("item_name")."<br>";
}
```

Now I called function1 and fucntion2 from another method.
It produced the output like this

```
inside function 1:item_value
inside function 2:item_value
```

If $CI is copy It should output

```
inside function 1:item_value
inside function 2:
```

But it doesn't.So I think it returns the original.